# Get the metadata of a file

Tags: java, metadata

It is possible to know the metadata of a file in java? and if it is, How to get the metadata of a file in java?

Comment: I think this is platform-dependent. Am I right in saying you're after the data the file system "attaches" to a file?

Comment: If that's what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

There is a basic set of metadata that you can get from a file.

```
Path file = ...;
BasicFileAttributes attr = Files.readAttributes(file, BasicFileAttributes.class);

System.out.println("creationTime: " + attr.creationTime());
System.out.println("lastAccessTime: " + attr.lastAccessTime());
System.out.println("lastModifiedTime: " + attr.lastModifiedTime());

System.out.println("isDirectory: " + attr.isDirectory());
System.out.println("isOther: " + attr.isOther());
System.out.println("isRegularFile: " + attr.isRegularFile());
System.out.println("isSymbolicLink: " + attr.isSymbolicLink());
System.out.println("size: " + attr.size());
```

Some things are platform dependent and may throw exceptions or return unexpected results.

You can read more at [Managing Metadata (File and File Store Attributes)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/fileAttr.html).

Answer (score 6):

FITS is a command line app that bundles many tools that can identify and characterize files (extract metadata). It also has a java API

- http://code.google.com/p/fits/
- http://code.google.com/p/fits/wiki/developer_documentation

Also there are numerous identification and characterization tools that can do similar tasks.
Apache Tika, Pronom Droid, Jhove, etc.

Answer (score 3):

### Get file Metadata from java program

```
package demo.test;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.nio.file.attribute.BasicFileAttributeView;
import java.nio.file.attribute.BasicFileAttributes;
import java.nio.file.attribute.FileTime;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;

public class FileCreationTime {
public  String getCreationDetails(File file)
    {       
       try{         
        Path p = Paths.get(file.getAbsolutePath());
        BasicFileAttributes view
           = Files.getFileAttributeView(p, BasicFileAttributeView.class)
                  .readAttributes();
        FileTime fileTime=view.creationTime();
        return (""+new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss").format((fileTime.toMillis())));
       }
       catch(IOException e){ 
        e.printStackTrace(); 
       }
       return ""; 
   }

   public static void main(String...str){
       System.out.println
           (new FileCreationTime().getCreationDetails(new File("D:/connect.png")));
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think is easy to use this folowing project to get informations from any files.

```
import java.io.File;

public class FileInfo{
    public static void main (String []args){
        File f = new File("file100.txt");
        if(f.exists()){
            System.out.println("Name: "+ f.getName());
            System.out.println("Path: "+ f.getAbsolutePath());
            System.out.println("Size: "+ f.length());
            System.out.println("Writeable: "+ f.canWrite());
            System.out.println("Readable: "+ f.canRead());
        }else{
            System.out.println("The File does not exist");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

With Java 7 you have [nio2](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/fileio.html) package, with new *Path.class* giving all you are looking for

Comment: You should see [answer] about links in an answer. I didn't downvoted because this links is most likely there to last (but Oracle can still move them...). You should add example in your answer or at least give some methods.