# How to get file's metadata (like author, categories company...) from Input stream using java?

Tags: java

I am getting input stream of the uploaded file in my application and I need to fetch the metadata of this file and process it. Is there anyway to get the metadata from Input stream, using java?

Thanks.

Comment: have you checked http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10824027/get-the-metadata-of-a-file? Not sure however whether this applies to streams as well...

Comment: There's not a lot of metadata that comes with an uploaded file

Comment: You can't get metadata from an InputStream; you need to know the filename. As for uploaded files, @MauricePerry is right.

Comment: BTW, are you talking about HTTP uploads?

Comment: @MauricePerry yes, this is a HTTP upload, done on client.

Answer (score 3):

You can't get *filesystem-level* metadata (what you see when you right-click on a file in Explorer and select Properties) from an `InputStream`; you need to know the filename. As for files being uploaded in an HTTP POST request, Maurice Perry's comment is right (it's impossible to get the filesystem-level metadata, as the client doesn't send them).

However, if you are talking about e.g. Office documents, you can get the metadata because they are contained in the file data itself, but you'd need to use a library that can read such files. For Microsoft Office, check out [Apache POI](https://poi.apache.org/).