# metadata of a BFILE

Tags: plsql, metadata, bfile

Is there any way, working with BFILEs, to collect the metadata information?
In my case, I have a table who's one of the columns is BFILE and points towards a location from the hard drive where I have text file(PDF, DOC, DOCX, TXT, HTML, etc.)

For example, I would need to collect the information from below screenshot.

[image: metadata required]

Is it possible, not manually entering into the a properties table?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create Java method for this purpose (read more [here](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/java.111/b31225/chthree.htm#CACJJHGI)).
And [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10824027/get-the-metadata-of-a-file) is solution how to get metadata in Java.

Comment: Is it possible to collect these metadata with VB.NET?

Comment: Didn't get your question.

Comment: I was not reading the Oracle's article about that but only the Java solution ... any way, thanks for the hint.