# Set current compilation time in a java class or jsf page

Tags: java, maven, jsf

I have a WAR archive compiled with maven.
I want to insert the compilation timestamp in a jsf page.

How can I change a string in a jsf page at compilation time ?
Example

```
<div>Compiled at (copilationTime)</div>
```

Must became

```
<div>Compiled at 2017-01-01 15:50</div>
```

If it is too complicate, I have an applicationscooped bean and i wrote

```
<div>Compiled at ${MyApp.compilationTime}</div>
```

But in my class how can i set 'xxxx'?

```
public class MyApp{
   String compilationTime = 'xxxx';

   public String getCompilationTime(){
      return compilationTime;
   }

}
```

Comment: I don't know if it is the exact thing you are requesting but you can generate a package file (called version.properties) with maven (in fact, with maven buildnumber plugin for example: http://www.mojohaus.org/buildnumber-maven-plugin/) and then retrieve the information from the file content (not from a variable).

Answer (score 1):

I think you're talking about a variation of resource filtering via `maven-resources-plugin`. The idea is this:

- You ask Maven to filter a certain resource (either a `src/main/resources` resource, or a variation of it, via `maven-resources-plugin`, a `src/main/webapp` resource via `maven-war-plugin`) in which you have placed the Maven pre-defined variable ${maven.build.timestamp}
- You make sure that the filtered resource is included in your project
- You read that resource either via `Class.getResourceAsStream` (or a variation of it), or via servlet mechanisms (depending where you place it).
- You use the value in your JSF.

Please note that you can ask Maven to replace a filter a variable directly in your JSF and cut some steps.

Answer (score 0):

From [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17540996/2998104) you can get a reference to a file:

```
final File classFile = new File(MyApp.class.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation().getPath());
```

and then from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10824137/2998104) you get the property:

```
BasicFileAttributes attr = Files.readAttributes(classFile, BasicFileAttributes.class);
String compilationTime = attr.creationTime().toString();
```

Comment: 1)  The file creation time and compilation time are not necessarily the same thing.  Files can be copied.  2) This won't work if the class is loaded from a JAR file.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [@CompileTime from Kolobok](https://github.com/ukman/kolobok#compiletime) and create a field

```
@CompileTime
private static long ct; // This field will contain compilation time in ms
```