# Transfer the file from source to destination only if the file is not being written into

Tags: java, file, talend

Basically i want to do a check wherein the file that needs to be picked up from the source to ensure they are still not being written into and then pull the file and move to destination which i have done

So i want to add a logic to check in java
presentime-filetime>5 minutes

How can i go about doing this in a java function and then process the file to a different location

Comment: Can you please explain what is presentime-filetime>5 minutes?

Comment: You have about 4 questions in one here, try to narrow it down to a specific issue. You can get file "metadata" and find out how long ago a fle was modified like this: [Get the metadata of a file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10824027/get-the-metadata-of-a-file)

Comment: presentime is the current sysdate/time